What are the parts of speech of "weekends" in "I travel weekends" and "I see her most weekends"?
What are the parts of speech of "weekends" in "I travel weekends" and "I see her most weekends" respectively?
Thanks for reply and thinking twice before voting~

(The plural is parts of speech.) Weekend is a noun in both cases. "I travel weekends" is an informal way of saying "I travel at/on most weekends" (at in British English, on in American).

@KateBunting Modified, thanks for your reply. But "weekends" could also be an adverb in dictionaries such as merriam-webster indeed. So...is there any chances that they are subject + verb + adverb structures?

This Merriam-Webster only gives it as a noun, verb and adjective.

@KateBunting Adverb, please refer to https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weekends

OK - I stand corrected. I think this is more of an American usage. We British would be more likely to say at the weekend or every weekend.

This is a fossil of the genitive used adverbially.  "Sundays the shop is closed".  Sundays = every Sunday.

That's old-school grammar lingo, BTW.  No idea what they'd call that kind of construction nowadays, as contermporary grammar tends to ignore linguistic history and treats the language synchronically.

I would suggest editing your question. "Parts of speech," in my opinion, can be a problematic and limited way of looking at language, if we treat them as buckets that we sort words into. Perhaps the real question is: these usages are a bit unusual; the first one seems almost like a transitive pattern, but "weekend" certainly isn't a direct object of "travel"; how does this usage work and why? These kinds of "how does it work" questions can be more productive than "how do I classify it."

It is equivalent in meaning to "[on] weekends" although "weekends" here is actually not a plural but a vestigial genitive  ending (from the Germanic side of English), though no one who hasn't studied the language historically would know that, so in one important sense the history is irrelevant.

Speaking of "I travel weekends".
